# Signed permutations and $ \operatorname{SO}(n) $

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, coxeter-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\O{O}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\Lift{Lift}$The subgroup of $ \SO(n) $ of determinant-$1$ signed permutations has order $ n!2^{n-1} $. I will call this group $ W_n $.

**Question:**

Is it true that $ W_n $ is a maximal proper closed subgroup of $ \SO_n $ if and only if $ n $ is not a power of $ 2 $ ?

**Context:** 
$$
W_3 \cong S_4
$$
is isomorphic to the symmetric group on 4 letters. It is a maximal proper closed subgroup.

It is also true that there are no closed subgroups of $ \SO(5) $ containing $ W_5 $ and none in $ \SO(6) $ containing $ W_6 $.

$$
W_2 \cong C_4
$$
is the cyclic group of order 4. It is not maximal. The infinitely many cyclic subgroups of order $ 4m $ all contain $ W_2 $.

And for $ W_4 $ we have a chain of strict containments
$$
W_4 \subsetneq \Lift(S_4 \times S_4) \subsetneq \SO(4)
$$
where $\Lift$ denotes the Lift through the double cover $ \SO(4) \to \SO(3) \times \SO(3) $.

I think that $ W_n $  fails to be maximal for every $ n=2^k $ a power of $ 2 $. Indeed it seems to me that $ W_{2^k} $ normalizes a certain extraspecial subgroup $ E \subset \SO(2^k) $ of order $ 2^{2k+1} $. The full normalizer of $ E $ is generated by the signed permutations together with tensor products involving
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Remark on relation to Weyl groups:

The group $ W_n $ above is of order $ 2^{n-1}n! $ and has structure $ C_2^{n-1}:S_n $. Also $ W_n $ is a Coxeter group since it can be generated by diagonal elements of order $ 2 $ together with transposition matrices of order 2 (because $ S_n $ is generated by transpositions). The Weyl group of the root system $ D_n $, denoted by $ W(D_n) $, is also of order $ 2^{n-1}n! $ and has structure $ C_2^{n-1}:S_n $ as noted by David E Speyer in the comments. And of course $ W(D_n) $ is also a Coxeter group.

I'm a bit surprised that $ W(D_n) $ is not isomorphic to $ W_n $. I guess that means $ W_n $ must not be an irreducible Coxeter group? Because otherwise we could appeal to the classification.

It is the case that $ W(D_3)=W(A_3)=S_4=W_3 $. I guess your claim is that while $ W_2=C_4 $  on the contrary $ W(D_2)=C_2 \times C_2 $. Something similar must happen to $ W_4 $ and $ W(D_4) $ with $ W_4 $ having more elements of order $ 4 $. In general I guess $ W_n $ will have more elements of order $ 4 $ than $ W(D_n) $ (with the exception of $ n=3 $ when the groups coincide).

Comment: By "contains", you mean "contains strictly", right? Finite subgroups are closed.

Comment: I added the condition for $W(D_n)$ that we consider only signed permutations of determinant $1$.  For your $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ question, you need to pick a maximal torus $T$ (there is no such thing as "the" maximal torus; they are all $\operatorname{SU}(n)$-conjugate, but the choice can matter for intersecting with $\operatorname{SO}(n)$), and a unitary representation of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$.  Presumably you mean the diagonal torus, and the representation of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ corresponding to the quadratic form $q(x) = \sum x_i^2$?

Comment: @LSpice yes thats the one I mean! Thanks for pointing out those clarifications.  And I included the edit from abx

Comment: Irrelevant nitpick: The Weyl group of type $D_n$ is the group of $(2n) \times (2n)$ signed permutation matrices where the product of the nonzero elements in the matrix is $1$. I believe that this is not isomorphic to the group of signed permutation matrices with determinant $1$. Both groups sit in short exact sequences $1 \to C_2^{n-1} \to G \to S_n \to 1$ (where $C_m$ is the cyclic group of order $m$), but this sequence is right split for $W(D_n)$ and not for your group. Look at the preimages of a transposition;  these preimages have order $2$ in $W(D_n)$ and order $4$ in your group.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think that is very interesting. I just assumed since they were both Coxeter groups with the same structure $ C_2^{n-1}:S_n $ that they would be isomorphic! Since $ W(D_n) $ appears in the classification of irreducible Coxeter groups does that mean that the group of signed permutation matrices with determinant $ 1 $ is reducible as a Coxeter group? I've edited my question to more accurately reflection the relationship of signed permutation groups to Weyl groups

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Also I think there's a small typo in your comment and $ 2n \times 2n $ should be $ n \times n $. Otherwise the size of the Weyl group $ W(D_n) $ is way too big.

Comment: Is it really clear that $W_n$ is a Coxeter group? $W_2 \cong C_4$ is not, but maybe that's exceptional. Also, even if $W_n$ is abstractly a Coxeter group, the given representation is not a reflection group (it contains no reflections).

Comment: @SeanEberhard, I don't understand your comment about $W_n$ being abstractly a Coxeter group, "but..." the given repn is not a reflection group: in my understanding, to say $G$ is a Coxeter group is to say that there is a generating subset behaving like reflections... But/and their images would behave the same way... Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett There is a technical difference between abstract Coxeter groups -- groups with a Coxeter presentation -- and reflection groups -- groups of isometries of a Euclidean space generated by reflections. E.g., $C_2 = \langle x \mid x^2 = 1 \rangle$ is a Coxeter group, but the subgroup of $\mathrm{O}(2)$ generated by rotation by $\pi$ is not a reflection group. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group. OP seems to be discussing $W_n$ as if it is a reflection group, though it isn't.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, ah, so "reflection group" refers explicitly to the image under a _representation_ (of an "abstract" Coxeter group, perhaps)... That is, further data beyond the Coxeter generators-and-relations... I get it.

Answer (score 4):

This is more an extended comment than an answer, but it wouldn't fit in the comments section.

There seems to be some confusion in the original question as well as the comments, between the group of monomial (or signed permutation) matrices in $SO(n)$ and the Weyl group. The monomial matrices form a group of shape $2^{n-1}S_n$. The extension does not split for $n$ even, but it has a subgroup of index two that does split, of shape $2^{n-1}A_n$. For the Weyl group, on the other hand, you need to choose a maximal torus, which is a product of $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ copies of $SO(2)$, and which then pairs up the coordinates. This is why $n$ even and $n$ odd behave differently. The Weyl group of $SO(2n)$ is $D_n$, while the Weyl group of $SO(2n+1)$ is $B_n$.

The full normaliser of your extraspecial group $E$ of order $2^{1+2k}$ in $SO(2^k)$ is a (usually non-split) group of shape $2^{1+2k}O^+_{2k}(2)$, where $O^+_{2k}(2)$ is the appropriate orthogonal group in characteristic two. See Griess, "Automorphisms of extra special groups and nonvanishing degree 2 cohomology", especially Theorem 5. However, this doesn't contain your monomial group for $k$ large, because $2^{2^k-1}.(2^k)!$ grows much more rapidly than the size of this group. This probably means that the "only if" part of your statement is wrong.

Finally, if an appropriate amendment of your statement is true (I haven't checked it), it should be possible to deduce it from Collins, "On finite subgroups of the classical groups" without too much trouble. See also Weisfeiler, "Post-classification version of Jordan's theorem on finite linear groups" for related statements.

Comment: The main theorem of Shangzhi Li, "The maximality of monomial subgroups of linear groups over division rings" shows that the monomial group is maximal in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ for $\geqslant 3$. But it's unclear how to reduce from that to $SO(n)$.

Comment: You can lift the transpositions of $S_n$ to the monomial subgroup of $SO(n)$ by introducing a diagonal $-1$ somewhere, as long as $n > 2$, so the monomial group *is* generated by involutions, but still it does seem unlikely that it is a Coxeter group.

Comment: Actually if $n$ is odd then the monomial group splits. A splitting map is given by sending $\pi$ to $\mathrm{sgn}(\pi) P_\pi$, where $P_\pi$ is the permutation matrix representing $\pi$. So $W_n \cong D_n$ after all if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Indeed. So I deleted my incorrect comment above. I hope that doesn't make a nonsense of this thread.

Comment: Proof that $W_n = 2^{n-1}S_n$ does not split if $n$ is even: there is no way to lift an $n$-cycle to an element of order $n$.

Comment: To preserve the main spirit of this question, which was intended to be more about the maximality of $ W_n $ in $ SO(n) $ rather than the relationship of $ W_n $ to Coxeter groups, I've created a new question about the relationship of $ W_n $ to Coxeter groups. I posted it to MSE here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731329/signed-permutations-and-coxeter-groups I would love it if you guys took a look at it, it's almost entirely based on your comments and answers! Also thanks for the recommendations of  "On finite subgroups of the classical groups" etc... I'll have to take a look!